# I get java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when trying to InitializeContext in mockejb test proyect WITH JAVA 1.8

Tags: java, mocking

I'm trying to make a simple test project with mockejb 0.6-beta2 and Java 1.8, but keep getting

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:166)
at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:144)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:116)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
at org.mockejb.interceptor.InterceptableProxy.create(InterceptableProxy.java:38)
at org.mockejb.jndi.MockContextFactory.getInitialContext(MockContextFactory.java:47)
at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:732)
at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:184)
at ar.com.clarin.suscripciones.servicios.impl.GestionarClienteComercialShould.setUp(GestionarClienteComercialShould.java:31)
```

When I try to run it. I keep geting this ExceptionInInitializerError I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, it seems to be on par with examples, I don't know, maybe the library is too old and out of date. The use of another ejb mocking library is also welcomed.

```
public class GestionarClienteComercialShould {

    private Context ctx;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // Setup the JNDI environment to use the MockEJB 
        // context factory
        MockContextFactory.setAsInitial();;
        // Create the initial context that will be used for binding EJBs
        ctx = new InitialContext(); 
    }
    @Test
    public void test() throws NamingException  {
                
                
        // Create an instance of the MockContainer
        MockContainer mc = new MockContainer(ctx);
        GestionarBPLocal gestionarBp = mock(GestionarBP.class);
        SessionBeanDescriptor dd = new SessionBeanDescriptor(
                   "java:comp/env/ejb/GestionarBP", 
                   GestionarBPLocal.class, GestionarBP.class,
                   gestionarBp) ;
        // Deploy our bean to the container allowing it to
        // be found via JNDI and tested
        mc.deploy(dd);
    }
}
```

It fails on line 32

```
// Create the initial context that will be used for binding EJBs
    ctx = new InitialContext();
```

Pls help.
PS: Here's my pom file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-inline -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.26</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockejb/mockejb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockejb</artifactId>
        <version>0.6-beta2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

HEre's the full stack trace just in case.

```
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:166)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:144)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:116)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
    at org.mockejb.interceptor.InterceptableProxy.create(InterceptableProxy.java:38)
    at org.mockejb.jndi.MockContextFactory.getInitialContext(MockContextFactory.java:47)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:732)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:184)
    at ar.com.clarin.suscripciones.servicios.impl.GestionarClienteComercialShould.setUp(GestionarClienteComercialShould.java:31)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @cd2dae5
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:200)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:194)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$2.run(ReflectUtils.java:56)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:46)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: Is there any more stacktrace?

Comment: Yes there is, I've just added it to the question.

Comment: Please add it to your question

Comment: There is no module system in Java 1.8, so it’s impossible to get this exception in Java 1.8. In other words, you are not using Java 1.8.

Comment: Great, I'll go check this out.